# what are the itemize symbols used by babel's spanish option?

Tags: babel, spanish

I like the default bullet symbols for `itemize` that `babel` sets up with the `spanish` option, and I would like to change the default latex symbols to match via `\labelitemi` et al.  What are the symbols that spanish' babel uses for `itemize`?

Comment: See § 2.1,*Listas*,  p.3 of the `babel-spanish` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find this in `spanish.ldf`:

```
\def\spanishsymbitems{%
  \es@itemize
    {\leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex
      {\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}%
    {\textbullet}%
    {$\m@th\circ$}%
    {$\m@th\diamond$}}
```

which is an indirect way for setting

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}%
}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\m@th\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\m@th\diamond$}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know what `\m@th` does?  The bullets symbols are already enclosed in `$`s.

Comment: @ltcomdata It is a precaution in case a style file sets `\mathsurround` to a nonzero value; the parameter sets an an additional kerning around math formulas, which is not wanted in this case. It's zero by default, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: I think you have an extra `}` at the end of the last `renewcommand` line?

Comment: @ltcomdata Yes, removed